# How to efficiently work together in Unreal Engine (with a Version Control system)

Tags: git, version-control, git-lfs, unreal-engine5

We started working with a team on an unreal engine (5.1) project and we would like to use a good system to work together, without sending individual files to eachother.

Our current solution is to use github & git LFS. Only problem is that we've hit a total usage cap of storage.

What would be recommended as the best tool/workflow to effectively work in a team on an unreal engine project?

Comment: Using your own server to host the common repo? It's not like a burden-proof approach.... you will have to deal with issues like "how do we do code reviews?" but at least you are no longer tied to limits from a provider.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for the Built-in Source Control System inside Unreal Engine if you want to work collaboratively as a team, Here is the link to the Source Control Document - [Unreal Engine Source Control](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/Basics/SourceControl/)

Unreal Engine comes with an integrated method that allows people to work together on their projects using version control software called Perforce, You can try that as well.